# Auto generate and save data to SlugField

Tags: django, django-models

Hello I have a function to auto generate data for my SlugField but i dont know how to implement a save method to execute it. Ive tried calling the function from the save method but it raises an error of 'instance not defined'. Any suggestions will help. Thanks.

```
def ran_str_gen(size=6, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(chars) for s in range(size))

def slug_gen(instance, new_slug=None):
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug=new_slug
    else:
        slug = slugify(instance.title)

    op = instance.__class__
    qs_exists = op.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
    if not qs_exists:
        new_slug = '{slug}-{ranstr}'.format(slug=slug, ranstr=ran_str_gen())
        return slug_gen(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug_gen()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the instance (`self`) to the `slug_gen` function, store the result in the `slug` field, and then make a `super()` call to save the model effectively, so:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slug_gen(self)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`django-autoslug`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug) to automatically create a slug based on other field(s).

---

> **Note**: Normally you should *not* change slugs when the related fields change. As is written in the article [*Cool URIs don't change* <sup>[w3.org]</sup>](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI), URIs are *not* supposed to change, since these can be bookmarked. Therefore the slug should only be created when creating the object, not when you change any field on which the slug depends.

Comment: Thanks. It doesnt seem to work. If I put the function inside the model class it raises an error **slug_gen is not defined** and outside the class it raises a **maximum recursion** error

Comment: @Grim: that is because then `slug_gen` calls `slug_gen`, and thus will result in infinite recursion.

Answer (score -1):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug=slug_gen()
```

Comment: Getting an error **slug_gen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'**